# Joining adjacent words (tokens) in a TDM for tidy analysis

Tags: r, token, text-analysis

I have documents that have strings similar to the following:

```
    textForAnalysis <- c("non-ifrs earnings numbers are report to be...")
```

Which I enter into a corpus

```
    textCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(textForAnalysis))
```

Then translate to a TDM

```
    textTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(textCorpus)
```

Then translate the TDM into tidy format for analysis

```
    textTidy <- tidy(textTDM)
```

When I print the text, everything is ok,

```
    textTidy

> textTidy
# A tibble: 6 × 3
      term document count
     <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1      are        1     1
2 earnings        1     1
3     ifrs        1     1
4      non        1     1
5  numbers        1     1
6   report        1     1
```

Except, I want to preserve the "non-ifrs" item as a single token (word).  I do not want to separate the "non-ifrs" phrase into "non" and "ifrs".

How can I maintain adjacent wordings, e.g. "non-ifrs" as a single "term" (non-ifrs) in my analysis/TDM?

Comment: Please add the required libraries (if any) to help me to understand the background of the functions.

Comment: Sorry about that Claude.

I am using the following packages: tm, dplyr, and tidytext.

Comment: At a first glance I would think that the function `TermDocumentMatrix` is the key. It allows for a parameter `control`. Read the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf#Rfn.TermDocumentMatrix) wrt. this parameter, especially the docs for [termFreq](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf#Rfn.termFreq) and there the documentation of `removePunctuation`. This control parameter might be set to `preserve_intra_word_dashes=TRUE` which should solve your issue. At the moment I have no R environment to try it. Will check it out later to provide a full answer.

Comment: If `removePunctuation` does not help take a look at the control parameter `tokenize`.

Comment: Thanks Claude, but I can't get either of those to work...  Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: The TermDocumentMatrix function continues to split the "non-ifrs" into "non" and "ifrs" tokens.

Comment: I could not replicate the issue with output of `TermDocumentMatrix(textCorpus)$dimnames$Terms`  being  `[1] "are"      "be..."    "earnings" "non-ifrs" "numbers"  "report"` , can you mention output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Interesting, because when I enter that command, I get the following:

        > TermDocumentMatrix(textCorpus)$dimnames$Terms
        [1] "are"      "earnings" "ifrs"     "non"      "numbers"  "report"

The "non-ifrs" is split to "non" and "ifrs"

Comment: BTW, the results of the sessionInfo() is:

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.7-1       NLP_0.1-10     tidytext_0.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paragraph in the documentation of `TermDocumentMatrix` which might be the key:

> This is different for a SimpleCorpus. In this case all options are processed in a fixed order in one pass to improve performance. It always uses the Boost Tokenizer (via Rcpp) and takes no custom functions as option arguments.

You have the assignment

```
textCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(textForAnalysis))
```

As you can see from `class(textCorpus)` the variable is an instance of `SimpleCorpus`.

Please use **V**Corpus instead of Corpus:

```
textCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(textForAnalysis))
```

Now you can apply all the necessary control parameters:

```
textTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(
  textCorpus, 
  control=list(removePunctuation=list(preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE))
)
```

The result is:

```
(textTidy <- tidy(textTDM))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      term document count
     <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1      are        1     1
2 earnings        1     1
3 non-ifrs        1     1
4  numbers        1     1
5   report        1     1
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Claude, but that works. Thanks!

Comment: @fibrou If it was helpful please consider to vote or to mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done!  Thanks again for the assistance.